# Land in or land on?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

”The aircraft  can land anywhere: in the snow, in the water and even in the freshly tilled field.”

In this sentence should I replace “in” with “on”?
What’s the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **on** to indicate that the airplane is touching and also **above** the snow, water or field.

[image: Airplane on snow]

Use **in** to indicate that the airplane is **surrounded** or **enveloped** by the snow, water or field.

[image: Airplane in snow]